# The reason why this world repeats the same situation infinitely

Tags: causality

The cause of everything belongs to everything

The cause of everything is everything

This is true for other reasons as well.

"Everything is the cause of everything"="If everything, then everything" = "If A, then A"

This is true by the Law of identity in mathematics.

and

In the causal cycle of A->B->C->A

The cause of "A,B,C" can be all of "A,B,C"

That is, all events are caused by all events.

So the cycle theory is true

This world is a world where the exact same situation is repeated infinitely.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions and answers are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anything closed can be edited to bring it within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [MetaPhil](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This site attempts to comport with a Q&A-style forum for answering questions largely about technical philosophical questions as opposed to providing a place for open-ended, opinionated metaphysical speculation.

Comment: Everything includes the cause of everything, therefore is there only everything (A). You just get A. No cycle A-> anything else. A may contain a cycle or not.

Comment: You don’t make any sense to me whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets try and reformulate this a bit more accurately

- the set "everything" contains all "things"
- a cause is a thing
- some things have causes

I don't see how your conclusion follows. You can imagine a universe where everything is destroyed, or there is only a single particle which travels in a line but never repeats or a fractal like universe with endless patterns but no repetition

Comment: If it is true that "the cause of everything is everything", then circular-causality is true because the cause of all events (everything) is all events (everything).

Comment: maybe, but you haven't shown that to be true. You are just saying that causes of things are included in the set of things. Fine but A can cause B and we can have the set (A, B) without the set causing A

Comment: "A->B->C->A" Can't this be called a set?

Comment: sure but you have to show that all sets loop

Comment: Since it is true when looped, can't it be called true?

Comment: Which one do I need to prove to be true? please teach me

Answer (score 0):

That's called *circular reasoning*, not "cycle theory". Also, *tautology*. Several facts of our existence are sustained in rationally circular facts. For example, the dictionary is a set of circular references.

Circular logic is useful sometimes due to the lack of deeper rules that can prove the rules our existence is founded upon. The dictionary is the perfect example of useful rationally circular knowledge, that is, knowledge that is based on itself.

For example, you know that after the night comes the day. But how is that true? Because it has always been so? So, *it is true because it has been true, and that, because it has been true* (circular argument). We have no other option than accepting such circular reasoning to predict that after this night a day will come. But strictly, the probability is never 100%; an unknown chemical reaction in the sun might convert it into dark coal in seconds; an unexpected planetary motion could divert the earth from its orbit leaving earth in permanent darkness; aliens could displace the sun; etc.

Comment: The law of identity is always true, apart from the fact that circular arguments can be wrong

Comment: @Dimer: "The law of identity is always true" False! In classical mechanics a particle is always a particle. But in QM...